# Best Container Type

Tags: c++, containers, stdvector, deque

I am working an application that requires a 'Sliding Window' which is simply a container of strings,

```
Window  = ["the", "dog", "is", "hungry"]
```

The application processes large text file and when certain conditions are met, the window adds a new string to the end and removes the first element,

I.e. say "now" is the next word to be added, then

```
Window <- Window.AddToEnd("now") and Window.DeleteFirst()
```

so it becomes, `Window = ["dog", "is", "hungry", now"]`

Every time the Window changes, a process is run over the elements where the order is important (i.e. the index is important).

Intially I went with a vector of strings and tried a deque. 
I was curious what people would think is the best?

To summarise, I need a container of strings that is indexed where VERY regularly a new element will be added + first element removed. I also need to iterate over the container A LOT.

Some other bits of info:

1. The String are never modified once in the container
2. The window elements are never changed (outside of the pop and push as discussed)
3. The size of the Window isn't know until runtime (something the user passes)
4. The Window never changes size, once initialized at the start, it stays that size for the whole application.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, Cheers David

Comment: You could also just use a ring buffer (though there isn't an implementation readily available in the standard library, but they're trivial to implement).

Comment: Well, either a list or a circular buffer will fit your needs. I'd propose to start with list.

Comment: [boost::circular_buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html)

Comment: A circular buffer is your best bet

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `std::deque`, which, according to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/),

> provide a functionality similar to vectors, but with efficient insertion and deletion of elements also at the beginning of the sequence, and not only at its end. But, unlike vectors, deques are not guaranteed to store all its elements in contiguous storage locations

You may also use a vector of fixed size, and saving the beginning index.

So it acts like a circular array. e.g.:

A vector v that initially is [a, b, c, d], with beginning index=0; after 'e' comes in, it is [e, b, c, d], but now with beginning index=1. The i-th element is `v[(beginning_index + i) % v.size()]`. This scheme is easy enough to be implemented by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a class template of a circular container that the size of the container is constant during run time but is set during instantiation of the class template. To use this the size has to be known or pre-calculated ahead of time; if you don't know what the size will be then you might consider using a similar algorithm as this without the template or another container. This does work very well if the size is not extremely large. As you can see in the `addString()` function when the elements being added start to exceed the size of the contained array, there is a for loop that is being called that has to shift everything in that array. This is fine for arrays in the order of 100s or 1000s of elements, but when you get to arrays that are 100,000 or 1,000,000 entries in size; this will bottleneck and be quite slow, however this does provide the mechanism of shifting everything to the left by one space and adding in at the end of the array, list or container.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>


template<unsigned Size>
class CircularContainer {
public:
    const static unsigned SIZE = Size;
private:
    std::string data_[SIZE];
    unsigned counter_;

public:
    CircularContainer() : counter_(0) {}

    void addString( const std::string& str ) {
        // In a real container this would be a member and not static
        // If you have a static here, and you have multiple instances
        // It will still increment across all instances.
        //static unsigned counter = 0;

        if ( counter_ < SIZE ) {
            data_[counter_++ % SIZE] = str;
        } else {
            // This function can be expensive on large data sets
            // due to this for loop but for small structures this
            // is perfectly fine.
            for ( unsigned u = 0; u < SIZE-1; u++ ) {
                data_[u] = data_[u+1];
            }
            data_[SIZE - 1] = str;
        }
    }

    std::string& getString( unsigned idx ) {
        if ( idx < 0 || idx >= SIZE ) {
            return std::string();
        } else {
            return data_[idx];
        }
    }

    unsigned size() const {
        return SIZE;
    }
};

int main() {

    CircularContainer<4> cc;

    cc.addString( "hello" );
    cc.addString( "world" );
    cc.addString( "how" );
    cc.addString( "are" );

    for ( unsigned u = 0; u < cc.size(); u++ ) {
        std::cout << cc.getString( u ) << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    cc.addString( "you" );
    cc.addString( "today" );

    for ( unsigned u = 0; u < cc.size(); u++ ) {
        std::cout << cc.getString( u ) << "\n";
    }


    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit." << std::endl;
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```

Now you could adapt to this; and exchange out the raw array of strings within this class and use the heap with pointer linkage and then all you have to do is reassign your `beg` and `end` pointers to the appropriate data since everything else in the middle will already be linked like pieces of a chain.

---

**Edit**

I have expanded this class to take any type, and instead of using a raw array of that data type, I replaced the array with the use of `std::shared_ptr` Here is the redesign of the above class. I also fixed the issue with using a `static counter` and made it a member.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

template<typename T, unsigned Size>
class CircularBuffer {
public:
    const static unsigned SIZE = Size;
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> data_[SIZE];
    unsigned counter_;
public:
    CircularBuffer() : counter_(0) {}
    ~CircularBuffer() {}

    void addItem( const T& t ) {

        if ( counter_ < SIZE ) {
            data_[counter_++ % SIZE] = std::make_shared<T>( t );
        } else {
            for ( unsigned u = 0; u < SIZE - 1; u++ ) {
                data_[u] = data_[u + 1];
            }
            data_[SIZE - 1] = std::make_shared<T>( t );
        }
    }

    T getItem( unsigned idx ) {
        if ( idx < 0 || idx >= SIZE ) {
            throw std::exception( "Array Buffer Out of Bounds!" );
        } else {
            return *(data_[idx].get());
        }
    }

    unsigned size() const {
        return SIZE;
    }
};

int main() {
    CircularBuffer<std::string, 5> cb;
    cb.addItem( "hello" );
    cb.addItem( "world" );
    cb.addItem( "how" );
    cb.addItem( "are" );
    cb.addItem( "you" );

    for ( unsigned u = 0; u < cb.size(); u++ ) {
        std::cout << cb.getItem( u ) << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    cb.addItem( "today" );
    cb.addItem( "my" );
    cb.addItem( "friend" );

    for ( unsigned u = 0; u < cb.size(); u++ ) {
        std::cout << cb.getItem( u ) << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;


    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit." << std::endl;
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```

It still uses a specified array, and the same technique to circle around the index of that array. The only difference here is that I'm using an array of `std::shared_ptr<T>`. This will cause the stored objects to be on the heap instead of local stack to the class template's scope. Cleaning up memory should be done automatically, but isn't always guaranteed. There isn't much of a need to keep track of a `head` & `tail` position unless if you explicitly need them, and that shouldn't be to hard to add to this class template.

Comment: @Jarod42 I know; but I just did that for the sake of simplicity since it will increment and the modulo of that and the size will always wrap around the index, and for this demonstration I only wanted to initialize it to 0 once.

Comment: ``static`` counter in ``addString`` is wrong. When multiple instances exist, they will mistakenly use the same counter. Besides, it is **not** circular buffer. Your answer is no difference than @Charles below.

Comment: @scinart that is true with multiple instances I can make a note of that in the original answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque).

```
#include <deque>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::deque<std::string> strs;

    // .. initialize;
    std::string tmp;
    while (true) {
        strs.pop_front();
        std::cin >> tmp;
        strs.push_back(tmp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) also shares the same functions.

---

If you want to limit how many times you allocate/deallocate memory, you can also use a `std::vector` like so:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> strs;

    // ...

    std::string tmp;
    while (true) {
        for (size_t i = 1; i < strs.size(); ++i)
            strs[i-1] = std::move(strs[i]);
     // strs.erase(strs.begin()); also works.

        std::cin >> tmp;
        strs.back() = tmp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This allows you to hold onto however many places you need and then only move the values around.

Comment: A bit one-sided for such a broad question.

Comment: I don't think contagious memory containers best fit the problem. So, `std::vector` isn't an good option.

Comment: Your version of `std::vector` works, but it's suboptimal. You should probably just do `strs.erase(strs.begin())`. At the very least you should be moving the elements.

Comment: That second solution is really bad and should not be used, that's a lot of unnecessary copying around.

Comment: @Frank I just added the `std::move` call. Does that help?

Comment: @Cornstalks 1) sure, but that's less illustrative; 2) yep.